# c# Can I call the built in Windows Explorer Map A Network Drive Functionality?

Tags: c#, networking

c# Can I call the built in Windows Explorer Map A Network Drive Functionality?
I don't want to reinvent the wheel, so is there a way to just call it using WMI?
I've found ways to map network drives, but I want to make sure the user credentials part is handled securely.

Comment: It looks like some people decided to mark your question as a duplicate even though it isn't. But I don't think there is an easy way (or a way at all in C#) to call the Windows Explorer dialog for mapping network drives.

Comment: If you add a new question I can share a class I use for this purpose, it does not open the Explorer window exactly but if you supply the UNC path and the desired local path it will ask the user for the credentials to use and will map the network drive, so you need only to add an small form with two fields to allow the user to select the UNC path and the local drive.